# sql query for deleting rows with NOT IN using 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a composite key composed of 2 columns, say Name and ID. I have some service that gets me the keys (name, id combination) of the rows to keep, the rest i need to delete. If it was with only 1 row , I could use

> delete from table_name where name not in (list_of_valid_names)

but how do I make the query so that I can say something like

```
name not in (valid_names) and id not in(valid_ids) 
// this wont work since they separately dont identity a unique record or will it?
```

Comment: Unless mysql has some magic juice, you have to use an OR AND pattern WHERE (key1 = val1 AND key2=val2) OR (key1 = val3 AND key2=val4) ad infinitum.

Comment: that is my fallback plan but i was wondering if there was an easier way to do this. The number of keys can be in hundreds potentially in extreme cases.

Comment: what kind of format is the list of things to keep in?

Comment: one column is a string (char(20)) and other is an int. the table has a blob column as well and is a partitioned table multiple gigabtes in size. it is partitioned on hash value of the int field in the key, in this case.

Comment: In Oracle you can do:

    SELECT * FROM person WHERE (id,name) IN ( (12,'Jim'),(2,'Bob') )

but not sure if this supported in mysql as don't have access to a suitable db.

Comment: I don't know too much about partitioning, but would `CONCAT` be an option? something like `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT(name,' ',id) NOT IN(SELECT CONCAT(valid_name,' ',valid_id) FROM retain_table)`

Comment: @Brian_Glaz Concat will work, but it will be extremely slow because I will lose the advantages of indexing and partitioning over such a huge table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use mysql's special "multiple value" `in` syntax:

```
delete from table_name 
where (name, id) not in (select name, id from some_table where some_condition);
```

If your list is a literal list, you can still use this approach:

```
delete from table_name 
where (name, id) not in (select 'john', 1 union select 'sally', 2);
```

Comment: @TP: This answer looks correct to me (and so does @billinkc's). They are both using a (temp or inline) table to store these value pairs you have. Since the table you want to delete from is big and the temp table would have many rows, it would be good if 1.you index the (temp or otherwise) table, 2.check the execution plans of all version of the query (or of the equivalent SELECTs) before running the DELETEs. ALso note that you could write a `NOT EXISTS` version as well. With proper indexes, I would think all 3 versions to be roughly the same in performance (but test with your data!).

Comment: One more comment. You could use `DELETE ... LIMIT 1000` and run it several times, until there are no rows affected.

Comment: "mysql's special...syntax" -- Actually, it's Standard SQL-92 (full) syntax. But it is nice that mySQL supports it. It would be really nice to have in SQL Server, very often requested feature, vote for it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors) :)

Comment: @onedaywhen: MySQL supports `(x,y) = (a,b)` and `(a,b) < (c,d)`, etc. But I think it doesn't support `(x,y) BETWEEN (a,b) AND (c,d)`. No idea why.

Comment: @ypercube: thanks for that. Partial support is better than none :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no I retract my comment about needing special juice or being stuck with (AND OR'ing all your options).

Since you have a list of values of what you want to retain, dump that into a temporary table. Then do a delete against the base table for what does not exist in the temporary table (left outer join). I suck at mysql syntax or I'd cobble together your query.  Psuedocode is approximate

```
DELETE
    B
FROM
    BASE B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        #RETAIN R
        ON R.key1 = B.key1
        AND R.key2 = B.key
WHERE
    R.key1 IS NULL
```

Comment: the Base table B in this case is a partitioned table multiple gigabytes in size. what are the performance issues that i need to consider, if any in this case ?

Comment: Couldn't begin to guess on the implications for MySQL as I sacrifice my goats to the SQL Server altar

Answer (score 1):

The `NOT EXISTS` version:

```
DELETE
    b
FROM
    BaseTable b
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS    
        ( SELECT
              *
          FROM 
              RetainTable r
          WHERE
              (r.key1, r.key2) = (b.key1, b.key2)
        )
```